# Transform URL into a link unless there already was a link

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this has been talked here, but no solutions were offer to the exact problem. Please, take a look...

I'm using a function to transform plain-text URLs into clickable links. This is what I have:

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>

window.onload = autolink;

function autolink(text) {

var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 

}

</script>
```

This makes

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
```

Looks like:

https://stackoverflow.com/

It works, but also replace the existent HTML links with nested links.

So, a valid HTML link like

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>
```

Becomes something messy like:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>">StackOverflow</a>...
```

How can I fix the expression to ignore the content of link tags? Thanks!

I'm a newbie... I barely understand the regex code. Please be gentle :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [jQuery JavaScript library](http://jquery.com/), this would look like (demo at http://jsfiddle.net/BRPRH/4):

```
function autolink() {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+\u0026@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+\u0026@#\/%=~_|])/gi,
        lt = '\u003c',
        gt = '\u003e';

    $('*:not(a, script, style, textarea)').contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var textNode = $(this);
            var span = $(lt + 'span/' + gt).text(this.nodeValue);
            span.html(span.html().replace(exp, lt + 'a href=\'$1\'' + gt + '$1' + lt + '/a' + gt));
            textNode.replaceWith(span);
        }
    });
}

$(autolink);
```

**Edit:** Excluded textareas, scripts, and embedded CSS. I note that this can also be done using [pure DOM's splitText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953095/are-there-any-text-selector-in-jquery/3953441#3953441), which has the advantage of not adding extra span elements.

**Edit 2:** Eliminated all ampersands and double quotes.

**Edit 3:** Got rid of < and > characters as well.

Comment: Excelent! But I'm using this in Blogger, and Blogger have a problem with ampersands. Blogger automatically replace all quotes with &quot; so I tried to replace "&" with &amp; (which worked well without jQuery), but does not work now (nothing happens). I tried too deleting the ampersands, but neither works.

Comment: Anyway, I learned some interesting things thanks to you. Maybe the script should exclude img tags as well...

Comment: @Matias: I've edited the script to eliminate all ampersands and double quotes, if you think that's a problem.

Comment: Also seems like Blogger replaces $('<span/>') with $("<span></span>").

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience, but i have lost. Blogger don't accept the A tag without the quotes. Blogger says: «Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "href".»

Comment: Blogger accepts your third edit as valid. Anyway, the script is not writing anything on the page. It keep changing '\u003c' with &#39;\u003c&#39; I do not want you to go crazy. Thanks for the help... I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is beyond the power of regular expressions. You might be able to write a regex that could avoid some links, but you wouldn't be able to avoid every existing link.

The good news is that a different approach will make the job much easier. Right now you using `document.body.innerHTML` to manipulate the HTML as plain text. To do it correctly that way, you will basically need to parse the HTML yourself. But you don't have to, **because the browser has already parsed it for you!**

The web browser allows you to access an HTML document as a series of object. It's called the **Document Object Model** (DOM) and if you do some reading on that, you should be able to learn how to traverse through the HTML, skipping over anything inside an `A` element, and using the regex you have on plain text only.