# Find word in HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find given word in HTML string and add a span around it.

What I am doing now is this:

```
function find(what:String,where:String)
{
    var regexp:RegExp=new RegExp(what,'gi');
    return where.replace(regexp,'<span>$&</span>');
}
```

It works well on words that are not inside HTML tags.
What I want is to ignore those that are inside HTML tags.

**Example:** find("spain")
Input:

```
The rain in <b class="spain">Spain</b> stays mainly in the <i data-test="Spain">plain</i>.
```

Output:

```
The rain in <b class="spain"><span>Spain</span></b> stays mainly in the <i data-test="Spain">plain</i>.
```

How can I achieve this, please?

Comment: Why did you come to the conclusion that you need regular expressions? You state the problem, and _we'll_ take care of the solution.

Comment: Do you have access to the DOM? It's a lot easier if you don't have to parse the HTML yourself.

Comment: I have it as a series of Strings that I concatenate to output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To account for html tags and attributes that could match, you are going to need to parse that HTML one way or another.  The easiest way is to add it to the DOM (or just to a new element):

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(container);  // this step is optional
container.innerHTML = where;
```

Once parsed, you can now iterate the nodes using DOM methods and find just the text nodes and search on those.  Use a recursive function to walk the nodes:

```
function wrapWord(el, word)
{
    var expr = new RegExp(word, "i");
    var nodes = [].slice.call(el.childNodes, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
    {
        var node = nodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType == 3) // textNode
        {
            var matches = node.nodeValue.match(expr);
            if (matches)
            {
                var parts = node.nodeValue.split(expr);
                for (var n = 0; n < parts.length; n++)
                {
                    if (n)
                    {
                        var span = el.insertBefore(document.createElement("span"), node);
                        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(matches[n - 1]));
                    }
                    if (parts[n])
                    {
                        el.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(parts[n]), node);
                    }
                }
                el.removeChild(node);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wrapWord(node, word);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/J8JJm/3

Comment: Hi Gilly. Thanks. It looks good, the only problem I'm having with this is that once I have the HTML string I want, I have to replace everything that's in the body (as the body's content I want to search) with the changed string.

Comment: gilly, be careful, if you throw another "spain" in there, look what happens to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/J8JJm/1/

Comment: Whoops!  I'll take a look when I'm back at my computer.

Comment: This problem seems to be harder than what I initially thought - oh well, these problems are fun

Comment: @vol7ron - I found two typos and corrected them in my answer and my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/J8JJm/3/): Started my loop at 1 instead of 0, and left the second arg off one of my calls to insertBefore.  Should work well now.

Comment: @Francisc - Don't worry about HTML strings at all, just pass `document.body` to the recursive function.  Eg, call `wrapWord(document.body, "spain")`.  The text will be replaced in place.

Comment: Ah yes, very nice, thank you Gilly. Thank you as well, vol7ron.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to process HTML in any reliable way using regex. Instead, parse the HTML into a DOM tree and iterate the Text nodes checking their data for content.

If you are using JavaScript in a web browser, the parsing will have already have been done for you. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953095/are-there-any-text-selector-in-jquery/3953441#3953441) for example wrap-word-in-span code. It's much trickier if you need to match phrases that might be split across different elements.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to replace on-page content or do I have to get the body element, pass it to the function then replace all of it with the parsed string, which seems bad.

Comment: The example code in the linked answer replaces the matched content with a wrapped version of that match. If you want, you could replace with something else by changing the code inside the `function() { ... }` passed to `findText`, for example by using `replaceChild` instead of `insertBefore`. Indeed you don't want to be touching HTML strings.

Comment: Thank you, bobince. Have a limequat on me.

Answer (score 1):

```
function find(what:String,where:String)
{
    what = what.replace(/(\[|\\|\^|\$|\.|\||\?|\*|\+|\(|\)|\{|\})/g, "\\$1")
          .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s:;'"~[\]\{\}\-_+=(),.<>*\/!@#$%^&|\\?]/g, "(?:&[0-9A-Za-z]{3,25};|&#[0-9]{1,10};?|[^\s<])")
          .replace(/</g,"&lt;?").replace(/>/g,"&gt;?").replace(/"/g,"(?:\"|&quot;?)")
          .replace(/\s/g, "(?:\\s|&nbsp;?)");

    what = "(>[^<]*|^[^<]*)(" + what + ")";
    var regexp:RegExp=new RegExp(what,'gi');
    return where.replace(regexp,'$1<span>$2</span>');
}
```

1. The first replace function adds a backslash before characters which have a special meaning in a RE, to prevent errors or unexpected results.
2. The second replace function replaces every occurrence of unknown characters in the search query by `(?:&[0-9A-Za-z]{3,25};|&#[0-9]{1,10};?|[^\s<])`. This RE consists of three parts: First, it tries to match a HTML entity. Second, it attempts to match a HTML numeric entity. Finally, it matches any non-whitespace character (in case the creator of the HTML document didn't properly encode the characters).
3. The third, fourth and fifth replace functions replaces `<`, `>` and `"` by the corresponding HTML entities, so that the search query will not search through tags.
4. The sixth replace function replaces white-space by a RE (`\s|&nbsp;?`), which match white-space characters and the HTML entity.

The only shortcoming of this function is that undocumented special characters (such as `€`) match any HTML entity/character (following the example, not only `&euro`; and `€` are valid matches, but also `&pound;` and `@`).

This proposed solution suits in most cases. It can be inaccurate in complex situations, which is probably not worse than a DOM iteration (which is very susceptible to memory leaks and requires more computing power).

*When you work with HTML elements which have Event listeners assigned through DOM, you should iterate through all (child) elements, and apply this function to every Text node.*

Comment: Hmm... I didn't think of it that way. I was thinking of looping through results and checking position of first occurence of `<` to first occurence of `>`. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: This will easily break, though.

Comment: @Francisc
I have improved my answer. The new function will be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Can you detail a bit what the each replace does and why.

Comment: @Francisc
Added a detailled explanation at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Pure JavaScript (based on Sizzle.getText from jQuery); [Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/U8LLv/](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/U8LLv/)

  ```
  var wrapText = function ( elems,regex ) {
      var re = new RegExp(regex);
      var elem;

      for ( var i = 0; elems[i]; i++ ) {
          elem = elems[i];

          // Get the text from text nodes and CDATA nodes
          if ( elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 4 ) {
              parent = elem.parentNode;
              re.lastIndex = 0;
              if(re.test(elem.nodeValue)){               
                  var span = document.createElement('span');
                  span.innerHTML = RegExp.$1;

                  if (RegExp.leftContext != ''){
                     parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(RegExp.leftContext),elem);    i++;
                  }

                  parent.insertBefore(span,elem);   i++;

                  if (RegExp.rightContext != ''){
                     parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(RegExp.rightContext),elem);   i++;
                  }

                  parent.removeChild(elem);
              }                   

          // Traverse everything else, except comment nodes
          } else if ( elem.nodeType !== 8 ) {
              wrapText( elem.childNodes, regex );
          }
      }

      return;
  };


  var obj = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  wrapText([obj],/(spain)/gi);
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use jQuery.

Comment: @vol7ron: If I were the OP, I'd probably reply with "I don't need more; I need an answer to the stated problem."

Comment: Setting `elem.nodeValue` on a text node will convert angle brackets to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.  You'll change the text, not the html.