# .replace not working on xmlhttp.responseText - Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have:

```
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {

    cu=$("#box1").val();
    cur=xmlhttp.responseText;

    cur=cur.replace(cu,'<strong>'+cur+'</strong>');  

     $(".box2").html(cur);

 }
```

I try that, and the replace just doesn't happen.

When I change `cur` to just have a value of normal text (`cur='my name is....';`) then it works fine.

I've tried changing the replace line to: `cur=cur.replace(cu,'found it');` - still nothing

This is all in the same function as the where the AJAX request takes place...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have value in responseText, is it not empty.. try alerting responseText to check..?

Comment: Its not empty because i display the value in a different div and it shows up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works if you fix one issue that may be a copy and paste error. You are setting `.html(current_response)`, but `current_response` is never defined.

http://jsfiddle.net/4LXWd/1/

But I doubt it works the way you want it to.  If `$("#box1").val()` is `world` and `xmlhttp.responseText` is `hello world hello world`, your result will only replace the first instance of world, and it will replace it with the entire response string, so you'll get:

```
hello <strong>hello world hello world</strong> hello world
```

Is that what you want?  If only replacing the first instance of the matched string is fine, you probably want this:

```
cur = cur.replace(cu, "<strong>$&</strong>");
```

**Edit:** But to replace every instance of the matched string, you'll need to use a regular expression:

```
cu = $("#box1").val();
var re = new RegExp(cu.replace(/[\[\]\\.*+?^${}()\/|]/g, "\\$&"), "g");
cur = xmlhttp.responseText;
cur = cur.replace(re, '<strong>$&</strong>');
$(".box2").html(cur);
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4LXWd/2/

Comment: Ahh, you just pointed out an editing mistake in the question, sorry, ill fix that. its supposed to be .html(cur). Basically, I want to replace (make bold) any char in the cu that is also in cur. I need to replace every char in cu, not just the first.

Comment: @Nav - To replace every matched character, you must use a regular expression.  See the edit to my answer and [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LXWd/2/).

Comment: ahh, that did the trick. Just one more thing: Do you know any way to escape some html stuff in the responceText (cur) because i have some div tags in there (cur=responceText=<div clas=something> actual value </div>) that i don't want the replace to effect. would that be possible?

Comment: @Nav - I've answered that question at least twice before.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7720056/361684 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/7380697/361684.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds `cu` is simply not found within the string `cur`.  Change that to a string literal that you know is in there in order to ensure that you actually replace something.

Comment: I tried that too. Still nothing. I know the issue lies within cur being xmlhttp.responseText because when i change cur to be a normal string (cur='hello there';), it works fine. It cant replace whats in xmlhttp.responseText for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous.  Have you confirmed that the 'if' statement is being executed at all?  There is a good chance those conditions are not met when they are first tested.

first test: `add alert('x');` inside that 'if' statement.

second test: delay that 'if' statement

```
setTimeout('fncCallBack()', 5000);

function fncCallBack() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {

    cu=$("#box1").val();
    cur=xmlhttp.responseText;

    cur=cur.replace(cu,'<strong>'+cur+'</strong>');  

     $(".box2").html(current_response);

 }
}
```

Comment: The if conditions are being met because i have changed the line: $(".box2").html(current_response); to $(".box2").html(cur); whicl will display the final (string with replaced chars) in div box2. And it does. So its not the if statement

Comment: Tried the delay, still nothing.

Comment: I forgot the () for the setTimeout call.  Updated.