# Selecting numbers with jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors

In a given DIV I wish to apply a SPAN to all numbers and only them. Is there a way to select numbers with jQuery ?

Comment: It would be easier to get help if you post some code

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't provide native selectors for text, but it is possible to achieve that effect. I adapted this from my answer to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951755/transform-url-into-a-link-unless-there-already-was-a-link), designing it to not mangle any links with numbers in the URL ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EF4cR/2/)):

```
function autospan() {
    var exp = /-?[\d.]+/g;

    $('*:not(script, style, textarea)').contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var textNode = $(this);
            var span = $('<span/>').text(this.nodeValue);
            span.html(span.html().replace(exp, '<span class="foo">$&</span>'));
            textNode.replaceWith(span);
        }
    });
}

$(autospan);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, jQuery provides no selector functionality against text nodes...you can loop through the `.contents()` and manipulate textnodes as you want, but jQuery won't help much here.

For example:

```
$("div").html(function() { 
  return $(this).text().replace(/(\d+)/g,"<span>$1</span>"); 
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WsMgW/), note that there are drawbacks to any approach like this, you're **changing the `.innerHTML`** which will destroy any event handlers, attached behaviors, etc.  Only use this if the content is *only* text to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use regular old javascript. Perhaps use a regular expression to find all numbers and replace them with span tags wrapped around them.

```
var str = "some text 123"
str = str.replace(/(\d+)/g, "<span>$1</span>");
```

you'd replace "str" with the contents of some elements. So let's say you wanted to do this over all

elements in your page

```
$('p').each(function(){ 
    var str = $(this).text();
    str = str.replace(/(\d+)/g, "<span>$1</span>"); 
    $(this).text(str);
 }
```

edit: you all type too fast