# Selecting numbers only in div with other characters, using jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the below sample I need to select the number in each div to display a color-coded message accordingly.

```
<div class="result_a">
  <label> A number </label>

  4
</div>

<div class="result_b">

  <label> B number </label>
  0
</div>

<div class="result_c">

  <label> C number </label>
  1
</div>
```

Using the below code only works if there was nothing but the number in each div. There must be a way to first strip all except the number in each div before selecting the number but I couldn't find such way yet.

jQuery:

```
$(" [class^='result_'] ").each(function() {
  var count = $(this).text();
  var dh = $(this),
        dhn = dh.attr("class").match(/result_(.*)/)[1];
  var aa = '0';
  var msg = '0';
  if (count < 1) {
    var aa = ('green');
    var msg = (' Your ' + dhn + ' is very good');
  } else if (count >= 1 && count < 3) {
    var aa = ('blue');
    var msg = (' Your ' + dhn + ' is bad');
  } else if (count >= 3) {
    var aa = ('red');
    var msg = (' Your ' + dhn + ' is very bad');
  } else {
    var aa = ('');
  }
 $(this).removeClass('red green blue').addClass(aa).text(count + msg);
});
```

I may be able to use the method applied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060063/11647629) (copied below) but not sure how to use this for my mentioned need (just selecting the number in each div and apply the above jQuery to).

```
function autospan() {
    var exp = /-?[\d.]+/g;

    $('*:not(script, style, textarea)').contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var textNode = $(this);
            var span = $('<span/>').text(this.nodeValue);
            span.html(span.html().replace(exp, '<span class="foo">$&</span>'));
            textNode.replaceWith(span);
        }
    });
}

$(autospan);
```

Any help on how to make use of the last code above with my code to get the required results or if there is any other way, would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parses your elem to only get the text;

```
$(".result_c").clone().children().remove().end().text()
```

no need for the code you provided